# give user access permission to selected folder only (AD 2003)

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I created a Global Security Group (MIS_Dept).  and user A as a member.

The folder (IT Folder) which i create that is exclusive to access for MIS_Dept only has a setup like this:

Sharing Tab : Do not share this folder
Security TAb: Administrator, Creator Owner, SYSTEM , MIS_Dept

Now, when I try to log-in to another user (not member of MIS_DEpt), I can also access IT Folder.

all i want is the user/group has an access to specific folde only.

e.g : IT Folder for IT personnel only
      Sales Folder for Sales personnel only.

hope someone here will try to help me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this from memory and not actually looking at an '03 server.  Try this.

Under the "Sharing" tab enable to share it and either leave the share name alone or change it to whatever.  Under the permissions (Permission button?) remove everyone in there.  Add the user, "Authenticated Users" and then click all of the check boxes except full control  I believe it's Read and Write only.

On the "Security" tab uncheck the box to inherit from parent and click "COPY" when it asks.  Then remove "Creator Owner" and click Apply/OK.

Try this.  You must share the folder in order for it to be accessed.  There are ways around that, but for this we'll keep it simple.